# SQL Agent job to execute a .bat file housed on a remote server

Tags: informatica, wmic, sql-agent-job

I want to execute a .bat script that lives on a remote server on that remote server, server B, from a different server, server A through a SQL-Agent job on server A. The script is for starting informatica workflows on Server B using the pmcmd command.

I cannot install SQL Server on Server B and call it locally using a SQL-Agent job that's why i have to run it through Server A.

I am trying to get this done through wmic command:

wmic /node:serverB /user:user /password:"pwd"> process call create "cmd.exe D:\s.bat"

but i keep getting "Access is denied" error whenever i run it.

Any ideas on how to resolve or does anyone have a better option.

Thanks,
Shawn

Answer (score 0):

Do you need it to run at some specific schedule? Like 5PM Mo-Fr? In such case use a scheduler on serverB. Cron or Windows scheduler.
Or, you need to run it after some specific event ON serverA? In this case FTP a file from serverA to serverB and use it as a trigger to execute the batch file (here's an example: https://superuser.com/questions/226828/how-to-monitor-a-folder-and-trigger-a-command-line-action-when-a-file-is-created).